# Email Reporting functionality, singleton or factory pattern design?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I am working on a project where upon certain conditions an email is to be sent to pre-defined list of users.
I am not sure of the best design pattern to follow. Only one email sender object will be used.

i have a class that will perform the reasoning of business rules the notifications in addition to a settings class for it, and a class that will perform the email sending.

I am working in C#.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to provide an answer.

Comment: I believe the answer is in your question, "Only one email sender object will be used". Sounds like Singleton

Comment: what i mean is if i have a class that i will most probably need a single object for, and its methods will be invoked from inside another class. Is singleton the best way to go ?

Comment: I really don't understand how you can use factory pattern here?! You can use workflow (WF) to model such situations

Answer (score 1):

In your question you mention, "Only one email sender object will be used". Considering that this is a requirement, Singleton is your best option.